# VS2013 Solution Switching

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have been running across an annoying behavior after updating to the latest visual studio for a few weeks now and wanted to see if anyone else is experiencing the same issues and/or knows how to avoid them.

It goes like this

1. Open TEST solution
2. Fix bug in TEST branch, checkin, merge to dev ect.
3. Close TEST solution
4. Open DEV solution
5. Wonder why nothing in Dev is right for about 40 minutes

Or this

1. Find bug in DEV
2. Update class library code to do some more correct thing
3. Fire up the debugger to verify changes
4. Wonder why the obvious change in #2 isn’t working

It seems like what’s going on is:

1. When trying to debug DEV code IIS Express still is running a copy of Test.
2. Changes to dependent libraries aren’t always reflected in the code that’s being debugged

What I’ve been doing to switch branches

1. Stop IIS
2. Shut down VS
3. Delete IIS Express temp files located at: C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files
4. Re-open VS
5. Back to coding

Any ideas? I wasn't having the same troubles in VS2012

Comment: I find when VS acts up it can also be beneficial to clear out the user settings for the solution by deleting the `.suo` file in the solution root.
I would also disable addons/extensions to make sure they are not interfering.

Comment: @Amicable That's a good idea, I'll power down resharper for a bit and see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer assumes you are using a VCS that checks out branches to different folders, like TFS, but not GIT).

This appears to be a new bug in VS2013 (and still present in Update 2)...  the issue is that the IISExpress applicationhost.config file is not updated to point to the location of your new branch.

You can manually update the file (located at Documents\IISExpress\config) or you can continue doing things like deleting the temp files which sometimes causes the file to get updated).

h/t: http://www.ninjacrab.com/2013/09/24/iis-express-misdirection/

For example, given this config entry for the original branch/file location

```
  <site name="Website" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr2IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Path\To\Original\Website" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54473:localhost" />
    </bindings>
  </site>
```

You can just edit the `physicalPath` to reflect the location of the new branch.

```
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Path\To\New\Website" />
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'm not sure if that ends up being any faster than wiping the temp files.

Comment: @AndrewWalters Yeah agreed - I tend to host in IIS-proper most of the time, which bypasses the issue completely (I have a batch file that updates the VirtDir location when I switch branch). I guess a .bat file to empty the temp folders added as an external tool to VS would be a good solution!

Answer (score 0):

I've been seeing this issue as well, well almost 100% the same.  My env just stops communicating with my services (ones also in my project) and continues to throw errors about not finding my user record in the db, which 100% exists.  So I run a little bat file I wrote to delete all the VS & IIS express cache, which usually get's me back up and running.  Sometimes I have to reboot and repeat the process again before I'm fully operational though.

I feel your pain re this issue, but I'm so happy to see you reporting it.  I was so torn as to how to begin to triage the problem without knowing if it was due to code, or a 2013/IIS express combo.  It's so hard to triage this issues when all you can say for certain is that stuff just doesn't work all the time.

I have my fingers crossed with you, in the hopes that someone can shed a bit of light on at least how to begin to analyze the components in order to narrow in on the cause of this.

Answer (score -1):

you can open two visual studio windows, middle-click on the visual studio icon in the taskbar, then you can have two different solutions open at the same time, if you had two screens, you could have one on each screen.

Comment: Right, the problem I'm describing is that IIS is getting locked into running on version of code when you want it to run another.